# angular reactive forms - using same formcontrol in multiple forms

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a component with ngSwitch which houses 3 forms (loginForm, signupForm and forgotForm), in which I use the same email control.

```
email: FormControl = new FormControl(null, [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.email
]);
password: FormControl = new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]);

constructor(){  
    this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
    });
    this.signupForm = new FormGroup({
        email: this.signUpEmail,
        password: this.signUpPassword,
        privacy: this.privacy,
        newsletter: this.newsletter
    });
    this.forgotForm = new FormGroup({
        email: this.email
    });
}
```

The controls are bound with via formControlName in the view

```
<div [ngSwitch]="activeSegement">
        <div *ngSwitchCase="'LOGIN.PAGE_TITLE'" class="segment-tab">
            <form [formGroup]="loginForm" class="login-form">
                <ion-item class="login-input-item">
                        <ion-label>{{ 'LOGIN.EMAIL' | translate }}</ion-label>
                        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="email"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div *ngSwitchCase="'SIGNUP.PAGE_TITLE'" class="segment-tab">
            <form [formGroup]="signupForm" class="login-form">
                ...
            </form>
        </div>

        <div *ngSwitchCase="'FORGOT_PASSWORD.PAGE_TITLE'" class="segment-tab">
            <form [formGroup]="forgotForm" class="login-form">
                ...
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Issue**

On first loading, inputting text into email and password controller in the loginForm reflect the change inside the controller but not the form. When I log out loginForm, the values are null. When I switch the tab and back, the values are registered (I believe in this case the form is instantiated with the values)

Is there some rule about using the same formcontrol in multiple forms I don't know about?

Comment: You cannot assign one FormControl to more than one component using formControlName.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10036